# Listview update sub cannot get values from aspx

Tags: vb.net, listview

HTML

```
<EditItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="LabelID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sysID")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Labelpar" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("parameters")%>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="LabelValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("value")%>'></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text='Update' CommandName="Update" />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text='Cancel' CommandName="Cancel" />
        </td>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

VB

```
Protected Sub OnItemUpdating(sender As Object, e As ListViewUpdateEventArgs)

    Dim svalue As TextBox = DirectCast(e.NewValues("value"), TextBox)
    Dim sParameters As String = DirectCast(e.NewValues("parameters"), Label).Text

    For Each row As DataRow In sysDT.Rows
        If row("parameters").ToString() = sParameters Then
            row("value") = svalue
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    lvConfiguration.EditIndex = -1
    BindListView()
End Sub
```

*if I breakpoint to the sub, svalue is nothing*

Error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   SiteMonitor-V1.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I used label id, and little changes in backend code

```
Dim svalue As String = TryCast(lvConfiguration.Items(e.ItemIndex).FindControl("LabelValue"), TextBox).Text
Dim sParameters As String = TryCast(lvConfiguration.Items(e.ItemIndex).FindControl("Labelpar"), Label).Text
```

This works fine